# Is this the Emperors sword?

Tags: warhammer-40k

After Pappa Smurf aka. Roboute Guilliman is back to W40k universe he is often holding a flaming sword in his hand.

[image: Smuff with sword]

This sword looks a lot like the sword the Emperor had before he got entombed.
Is there any mention that this sword is actually the Emperors own sword?

[image: Emperor]

Very similar crossguard, Sword is flaming, red gem in both swords...

Comment: Various sources say yes though I don't have access to the source material to confirm and I don't know if the sources are reputable. RE: [wikia](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Emperor%27s_Sword_(Weapon)), [Lexicanum](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Emperor%27s_Sword_(Weapon)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### It sure is

According to the [GW description](https://www.games-workshop.com/en-IE/Roboute-Guilliman-Ultramarines-Primarch-2018) of the Guilliman model itself:

> **He clutches the burning sword of the Emperor**, and wears the Hand of Dominion, with which he can tear apart tanks and crush his foes with ease. Yet it is the Primarch’s strategic brilliance that is his greatest weapon, dooming enemies to defeat before the battle has even begun.

and

> **The Emperor’s Sword, held in his right hand**, is a huge blade that burns with righteous fury (and fire)

Purely going by the language used by GW, the lower case *s* in sword here: *He clutches the burning sword of the Emperor* would suggest this sword belonged to the Emperor, as opposed to just being a sword called the *Sword of the Emperor*.

But it is also named: The Emperor's Sword / Sword of the Emperor.

---

And also the 40k wiki entry on the [The Emperor's Sword](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Emperor%27s_Sword_(Weapon)):

> **The Emperor's Sword, also called the Sword of the Emperor, is a famed relic blade that was wielded by the Emperor of Mankind Himself during the Great Crusade and was eventually passed on to the resurrected Primarch Roboute Guilliman in 999.M41** by the Archmagos Dominus Belisarius Cawl in the wake of the 13th Black Crusade and the Ultramar Campaign, just before he assumed the mantle of Lord Commander of the Imperium for the second time. The weapon had been kept safely in Cawl's possession on Mars for over 10,000 standard years, since the end of the Horus Heresy and Guilliman's first tenure as the Lord Commander.

Comment: Do you have a source from the source material? I found the wikia quote earlier but wasn't sure how accurate the wikia is for 40k.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The sources are listed in the wiki page. The fact GW themselves say it leads me to believe it is true though.

Comment: As far as I can tell the wikia statements don't reference any particular source though so it's hard to tell what is sourced and what isn't. I do believe this answer is correct, from what I've found, was just wondering if you had any quotes from the source material though.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Here is the passage from Chapter 22 : "Gulliman smoothly drew his father's sword. Mathieu gasped. He had seen the Sword of the Emperor drawn on several occasions. Every time, he bore witness to a miracle. On leaving the scabbard, the blade burst into flame."

Comment: @Odin1806 thanks for sealing the deal for me. i was not 100% decided but that seals it for me. Dafts answer is then correct. Wish i could give you more upvotes.

Comment: @Cherubel - No Problem. Happy to help!